# How to update from addStream to addTrack correctly?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am using [webrtc-adapter](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) v2.0.8, when I update my codes from

```
this.peerConnection.addStream(this.myStream);
```

to

```
this.myStream.getTracks().forEach(track => this.peerConnection.addTrack(track, this.myStream));
```

based on the [demo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/addTrack). 
I got the error

> getUserMedia:  TypeError: _this.peerConnection.addTrack is not a
>   function

in my browser (Chrome 56.0.2906.0 dev) console.

How can I use `addTrack` correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE on July 15, 2019**: Checked again today. Chrome 64 has support already.

---

Chrome has not supported `addTrack` yet:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=705901

Also check **Browser compatibility** section [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/addTrack#browser_compatibility).

Comment: Unfortunately polyfilling `addTrack` on top of `addStream` is real hard.

Comment: any update on this i'am getting the error as op said when changed addstream to addtrack.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`this.peer.addStream(this.myStream)`

Note: peer object has a method 'addStream' which accepts stream object as a parameter

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.